# Disable undo in the eclipse project explorer

Tags: eclipse, undo, project-explorer

I like eclipse but it's really annoying that "Undo" works in the "Project Explorer".

Is it possible to disable this functionality, and how?

Comment: There is no user setting to disable undo in the project explorer (why should there?) You could write a custom plug-in that disables the undo command in this context, but I guess that's not what you want. But out of curiosity, what exactly is 'annoying'?

Comment: random files tend to disappear with no warning and no way of recovering them without a backup... but it sound like it's a bug as Naren pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for do you want disable the cntrl+z option when you focused on the project explorer.

I can see it is a bug in the eclipse as per the link below.[bug cntrl+z](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344724)

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want, just seems strange that it isn't possible to disable this functionality if its buggy...

Comment: my bad it can be disabled by window->preferences->general->keys
and then set the undo command to only work when editing text